# Replacing Android service used by an application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have a library that I distribute to third parties that contains a service.  It is also obfuscated.  Is there any way to have the third-party application (that I don't have access to the source code to) use the service I can build locally?

I want to do things like profile the service behaviour in a real environment or use various debug settings/debug code that is otherwise unavailable.

Comment: To clarify, I could probably get changes made to the built third-party APK, but I don't have access to the source code to build everything from scratch.

Comment: If the names that are part of the api do not get obfuscated in the build and there is no objection to you decompiling and recompiling the apk, then there are tools you could use to do this.  You would end up with a different signature, which would force you to clear any data stored by the genuine app, and might break access to some services - google maps for example would not work if the signature no longer matched the compiled in api key.

Answer (score 0):

Well a service can be made remote and it can be distributed separately as its own application that is then binded to by applications that want to use it.  Not sure if this helps but you can create your service as a remote service and deploy it separately from the apps that use it.